# Ruby (ver 2.2.9) need to fire method on association changes

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, activerecord

I have a class:

```
   class Foo < ActiveRecord::Base

     has_and_belongs_to_many :bar
     after_save :do_the_thing #hoping when bars are changed, Foo fires do_the_thing

     def do_the_thing
       #Something happens here
     end
   end
```

However, when the associations between `foo` and `bar` change (such as a `bar` has been deleted that's associated with a `foo`, added to an existing foo, or moved from one foo to another?) it doesn't trigger a change in `foo`. How do I get `foo`'s method to trigger when it's associations change?

Comment: What you want is [association callbacks](https://guides.rubyonrails.org/association_basics.html#association-callbacks). Not sure if they are available for `has_and_belongs_to_many` which is rather limited compared to `has_many through:`.

Comment: I'll give it a shot, just in case.

Comment: no such method, unforunately. Guess it's not on has_and_belongs_to_many

Comment: Then use `has_many through:` - it does exactly the same thing but is less limited.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think that if you want to react to changes in `Bar` (such as deletions), you need to add callback there, e.g.

```
class Bar < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_and_belongs_to_many :foos

  after_destroy :notify_foos_destroyed
  after_save :notify_foo_save

  def notify_foos_destroyed
    foos.each{|foo| foo.call_a_method} 
  end

  def notify_foos_saved
    foos.each{|foo| foo.call_another_method} 
  end
end
```

EDIT:
If you want to react to assignment changes, you need to add callbacks to a linking model:

```
class Bar < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :foos, through: :foo_bar_link
  has_one :foo_bar_link
end


class Foo < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :bars, through: :foo_bar_link
  has_one :foo_bar_link
end

class FooBarLink < ActiveRecord::Base
  self.table_name = 'foo_bar_linking_table'
  belongs_to :bar
  belongs_to :foo

  after_save :notify

  def notify(*)
    bar.call_a_method
    foo.call_a_method
  end
end
```

Comment: ... would this fire if a bar was moved from one foo to another?

Comment: Actually in this case not, because it's something that causes save on the linking model. Instead of using hbtm, you can define the linking model explicitly and add a callbacks. This model would `belongs_to :foo` and `belongs_to :bar`. Foo and bar would `has_one :foo_bar_link` and `has_many :foo through`

Comment: This is on a codebase that's been running awhile, would that break the existing link created by ActiveRecord?

Comment: Not, if you set the linking model to use the existing table using self.table_name = "name_of_the_linking_table"

Comment: Include that as an option into the answer and I'll go ahead an accept it.

Comment: Are you sure you can even use the `through:` option with HABTM? Looks strange to me.

Comment: You're right one can't do that: https://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Associations/ClassMethods.html#method-i-has_and_belongs_to_many. Fixed, thx @max

Answer (score 1):

This is really trivial if you use `has_many through:` instead of `has_and_belongs_to_many` together with [association callbacks](https://guides.rubyonrails.org/association_basics.html#association-callbacks).

Both create many to many associations. But `has_and_belongs_to_many` only handles cases with zero complexity. See [Why you don't need has_and_belongs_to_many](https://flatironschool.com/blog/why-you-dont-need-has-and-belongs-to-many) for a detailed explanation.

```
class Foo < ApplicationRecord
  has_many :foo_bars
  has_many :bars, through: :foo_bars, after_add: :do_the_thing

  def do_the_thing(bar)
    puts "Doing da thang"
  end
end

class FooBar < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :foo
  belongs_to :bar
end

class Bar < ApplicationRecord
  has_many :foo_bars
  has_many :foos, through: :foo_bars
end
```

```
irb(main):001:0> foo = Foo.create
   (0.3ms)  BEGIN
  SQL (1.2ms)  INSERT INTO "foos" ("created_at", "updated_at") VALUES ($1, $2) RETURNING "id"  [["created_at", 2019-10-11 21:31:54 UTC], ["updated_at", 2019-10-11 21:31:54 UTC]]
   (0.6ms)  COMMIT
=> #<Foo id: 6, created_at: "2019-10-11 21:31:54", updated_at: "2019-10-11 21:31:54">
irb(main):002:0> foo.bars.create
   (0.1ms)  BEGIN
  SQL (0.6ms)  INSERT INTO "bars" ("created_at", "updated_at") VALUES ($1, $2) RETURNING "id"  [["created_at", 2019-10-11 21:32:00 UTC], ["updated_at", 2019-10-11 21:32:00 UTC]]
  SQL (1.8ms)  INSERT INTO "foo_bars" ("foo_id", "bar_id", "created_at", "updated_at") VALUES ($1, $2, $3, $4) RETURNING "id"  [["foo_id", 6], ["bar_id", 5], ["created_at", 2019-10-11 21:32:00 UTC], ["updated_at", 2019-10-11 21:32:00 UTC]]
Doing da thang
   (0.7ms)  COMMIT
=> #<Bar id: 5, created_at: "2019-10-11 21:32:00", updated_at: "2019-10-11 21:32:00">
```